# How to enable full debug mode in FastMM4?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, fastmm

I cannot figure out how to use FastMM. I have downloaded it from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) and placed FastMM4Messages.pas and FastMM4.pas at the top of my dpr file.

I now call this procedure to leak some memory:

```
procedure testMemoryFastMM;
    var
     str : TStringList;
       begin
    str:=TStringList.Create;
    str.add('MemChk');
    str.SaveToFile('C:\leeMemChk.txt');
  end;
```

and get this message
 [image]

How do I enable these FullDebugMode and LogMemoryLeakDetailsToFile switches?

Comment: http://delphiprogrammingdiary.blogspot.com/2018/09/fastmm-and-how-to-use-in-delphi-project.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

FastMM4 comes with an include file (FastMM4Options.inc). This file contains all of FastMM4's options, some of which are commented out. Uncomment to activate them and then include the inc file in your project by placing `{$INCLUDE FastMM4Options.inc}`in your dpr file.

Comment: yes..the FastMM4Options.inc file is there...i uncommented the..{$define LogErrorsToFile } and  {$define LogMemoryLeakDetailToFile} but still the comments says that " {Set this option to log all errors to a text file in the same folder as the
   application. Memory errors (with the FullDebugMode option set) will be
   appended to the log file. Has no effect if "FullDebugMode" is not set.}"  ....so how to set "FullDebugMode"

Comment: `FullDebugMode` is one of the available defines in that same .inc file.

Comment: There is a Gui of Fastmm4 Option Interface. see http://jedqc.blogspot.be/2007/07/new-fastmm4-options-interface.html