# Delphi 7 memory issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have an Instant messenger server application, which i have been working on, it uses Indy10 server component, and uses only 3 user defined objects for holding some information related to logged in users. The issue is really strange

If there are under 500 connections to the server it works fine and the memory usage remains under 100mb, but when the connection count exceeds 500-600, then the server massively start eating memory, and cosume upto 2gb of ram in an hour or so and then stops responding. I tried checking for the issue with eurekalog but after closing the application it reported only a few mb of leaks and those leaks were of some exception messages and i have no clue where it is happening.

Is there any tool which i can use to help me find the reason where and when the memory issue starts.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[FastMM4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) can help you track down memory leaks. It's the default memory manager since Delphi 2006, but can be used in Delphi 7 as well. There are lots of posts here about using it, as well as those that can be located with Google and with the source and configuration files it includes. A useful link here might be [How to enable full debug mode in FastMM4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8601504/62576) or the series on [Using FastMM4 for debugging your memory allocations](http://wiert.me/2009/07/29/delphi-fastmm-using-fastmm4-for-debugging-your-memory-allocations-part-1-introduction/).