# How to deploy with eurekalog?

Tags: delphi, deployment, eurekalog

I'm having a problem trying to deploy an application with eurekalog to solve some memory leaks that happen in a specific scenario. When I configure my app project to use eurekalog under the delphi IDE and run through the IDE, it works perfectly, reporting leaks and exceptions. When I run the exe outside the IDE it doesnt report anything.

Is there a special configuration to deploy the application with eurekalog?

thanks

Comment: I use EurekaLog 6.1.04 with Delphi XE. Are you sure EurekaLog is not generating a .elf file in the same folder of you application? Everytime EurekaLog has something to report it generates a .elf file and eventually sends an e-mail containing such a file.

Comment: im using version 7 of eurekalog. only when running the project through the ide, it reports and generates the .elf file (in version 7 it's .el). If i run outside the IDE, by double clicking the .exe, it doesnt show the report dialog when closing the app and doesnt generate the .elf

Comment: EurekaLog has their own [tech support system](http://news.eurekalog.com/forumdisplay.php?f=8). Have you asked there first?

Answer (score 1):

The IDE won't report anything... there should be a window from EurekaLog provinding call stack and some other info. From [EurekaLog official documentation](http://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/index.php?configuring_project_itself.php):

> Short answer:
>
> 1. To solve problems with non-working, partial or misleading call stack - clear .map, .tds and .dcu files of your project and be sure to:
>      ●(Delphi) enable "Compiler"/"Debug information", "Linker"/"Map file" = "Detailed".
>      ●(C++ Builder) enable "C++ Compiler"/"Debugging"/"Debug information", "C++ Compiler"/"Debugging"/"Debug line number information", "C++ Linker"/"Full debug information", "C++ Linker"/"Output"/"Map file" = "Detailed segment map".
> 2. To increase help level of EurekaLog:
>      ●(Delphi) enable "Compiler"/"Stack frames", "Compiler"/"Range checking" and "Compiler"/"Use Debug DCUs" options and make "Project"/"Build all".
>      ●(C++ Builder) disable "C++ Linker"/"Output"/"Map with mangled names" option, enable CodeGuard for you application (some options may conflict with EurekaLog).

If that doesn't help, you should provide more information: What happens when an exception is triggered by your application? Does an EurekaLog window appears?

Comment: yes it does, but only when running through delphi. when I execute the .exe outside delphi, no eurekelog window appears, nothing is reported. All the compiler/linker options in the documentation are correctly set in my project. Im also using eurekalog 7

Comment: Check if EurekaLog is activated and project type correctly selected (I believe it wouldn't work inside the IDE if it wasn't, but who knows?): http://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/use.php

Answer (score 0):

EurekaLog is overkill for what you want (it will also increase the compilation time 3-5 times). If all you want is to detect a memory leak, use FastMM4. It is already delivered with Delphi and is cheaper that EurekaLog (cheap=free :) ).

[How to enable full debug mode in FastMM4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601504/how-to-enable-full-debug-mode-in-fastmm4)

PS: if you really MUST use EurekaLog, use v6. v7 is totally unstable.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to turn off ["Active only when running under debugger" option](https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/memory_leaks_page.php), which is enabled by default.